# PHPStorm - Link external SFTP-folders into project

Tags: sftp, symlink, phpstorm

the issue i am fighting through is a bit complicated. Ill explain the setup envoironment to you first.

1. I am using PHPStorm to work on a Symony2 Project.
2. My Apache is hosted on a Debian-VM connected to PHPStorm via "Deployment Tool".
   /* So far: I can edit code and update the server automaticaly on save. Works*/

My problem now is, that i am using the composer, which is ment do get me the right bundles into the vendor folder.
I WANT to create kind of a symlink from the server directly into the project.
I DONT WANT to download the vendor folder from the server hard into the project.

COMPACT:
I want to create a symbolic link within a PHPStorm project. Linking a folder from a server into the Project. The linked in folder should be unidirectional updated on source change. The Classes and Namespaces should be known to the Project.

Is there any native way to get this done?
Or does anyone know a plugin which could handle such affairs?

I hope i expressed my point clearly :/ Please ask, if anything is unclear.

Greetings and thanks upfront.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do directly from PhpStorm, [see the related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1398). You can use some third-party tool like ExpanDrive to map a server directory to the drive letter by SFTP and then add this local directory as a content root to your PhpStorm project. Note that it may affect the performance dramatically.